# How can I hash passwords in postgresql?

Tags: security, postgresql, hash, cryptography, salt

I need to hash some passwords with salt on postgresql, and I haven't been able to find any relevant documentation on how to get that done.

So how can I hash passwords (with some salts) in postgresql?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question, and I'm much more familiar with the cryptographic theory now, so here is the more modern approach:

### Reasoning

- Don't use md5.  Don't use a single cycle of sha-family quick hashes.  Quick hashes help attackers, so you don't want that.
- Use a resource-intensive hash, like bcrypt, instead.  Bcrypt is time tested and scales up to be future-proof-able.
- Don't bother rolling your own salt, you might screw up your own security or portability, rely on gen_salt() to generate it's awesome unique-to-each-use salts on it's own.
- In general, don't be an idiot, don't try to write your own homegrown crypto, just use what smart people have provided.

### Debian/Ubuntu install packages

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql   // (of course)
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev   // (gets bcrypt, crypt() and gen_salt())
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql   // (optional if you're using postgresql with php)
```

### Activate crypt() and bcrypt in postgresql in your database

```
// Create your database first, then:
cd `pg_config --sharedir` // Move to the postgres directory that holds these scripts.
echo "create extension pgcrypto" | psql -d yOuRdATaBaSeNaMe // enable the pgcrypo extension
```

### Use crypt() and gen_salt() in queries

Compare :pass to existing hash with:

```
select * from accounts where password_hash = crypt(:pass, password_hash);
//(note how the existing hash is used as its own individualized salt)
```

Create a hash of :password with a great random salt:

```
insert into accounts (password) values crypt(:password, gen_salt('bf', 8));
//(the 8 is the work factor)
```

### From-in-Php bcrypt hashing is slightly preferrable

There are `password_*` functions in php 5.5 and above that allow trivially simple password hashing with bcrypt (about time!), and there is a backward compatibility library for versions below that.  *Generally* that hashing falls back to wrapping a linux system call for lower CPU usage anyway, though you may want to ensure it's installed on your server.  See: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat (requires php 5.3.7+)

### Be careful of logging

Note that with pg_crypto, the passwords are in plaintext all during the transmission from the browser, to php, to the database.  This means they can be logged *in plaintext* from queries if you're not careful with your database logs. e.g. having a postgresql slow query log could catch and log the password from a login query in progress.

### In Summary

Use php bcrypt if you can, it'll lessen the time that the password remains unhashed.  Try to ensure your linux system has bcrypt installed in it's `crypt()` so that is performant. Upgrade to at least php 5.3.7+ is highly recommended as php's implementation is slightly buggy from php 5.3.0 to 5.3.6.9, and inappropriately falls back to the broken `DES` without warning in php 5.2.9 and lower.

If you want/need in-postgres hashing, installing bcrypt is the way to go, as the default installed hashes are old and broken (md5, etc).

Here are references for more reading on the topic:

- http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgcrypto.html
- https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: So, it's better to do hashing with pgcrypto vs on the app-side? In general, should routine work hashing, guid generation, etc. be done by pg instead of the app? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer above with more detail.  Since pg_crypto requires that the plaintext of the password hit the database queries, with the potential problems when incidental query loggings occurs, I recommend trying for in-php `password_hash()` first these days if you can make it happen.  Bcrypt is the current state-of-the-art in password hashing, so it blows away the other options, whether in postgresql or php.  Bcrypt hashing is resource-intensive by design, so if you use it in php, try to get bcrypt available from crypt() to decrease your server's resource use.

Comment: don't use md5, it's broken, postgres hear's "use md5" because that's what it uses to hash it's passwords...

Comment: I had a GIANT freakout and rewrote a bunch of code after reading about the logging issue here.  Then I realized that I was using parameterized queries, which meant that my db logs didn't have plaintext content in them.  Notably, when using pgp encryption, I needed to pass my public/private key string as a parameter as well to avoid logging

Comment: Postgres 11+ has the [`scram-sha-256`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-password.html) password scheme (from [RFC 7677](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7677)). As it utilizes [SCRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salted_Challenge_Response_Authentication_Mechanism), it might be an alternative to PHP's `password_*`-functions in some cases.

Comment: To my understanding, sha-256 is a fast hash, you want slow hashes for passwords, to slow an attacker if they get a copy of your database data.

Answer (score 15):

An application should hash its passwords using key derivation function like bcrypt or pbkdf2.  [Here is more information on secure password storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords/401684#401684).

... but sometimes you still need cryptogrpahic functions in a database.

You can use [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html) to get access to sha256 which is a member of the sha2 family.  Keep in mind sha0,sha1 md4, and md5 are very broken and should **never** be used for password hashes.

The following is an alright method of hashing passwords:

```
digest("salt"||"password"||primary_key, "sha256")
```

The salt should be a large randomly generated value.  This salt should be protected,  because the hashes cannot be broken until the salt is recovered.  If you are storing the salt in the database then it can be obtained along with the password hash using sql injection.  Concatenating the primary key is used to prevent 2 people from having the same password hash even if they have the same password.  Of course this system could be improved,  but this is much better than most systems I have seen.

Generally it is best to do hashing in your application before it hits the database.  This is because querys can show up in logs,  and if the database server was owned then they could enable logging to get clear text passwords.

Comment: Yep, I was a bit late. Deleted my answer, as you were first and more detailed ;).

Comment: @T Duncan Smith   thanks man,  i gave you some points for being a good SO member.

Comment: Hmmm, the logging issue is a good point, I suppose, but for practical reasons I want to be able to run a sql statement to un-personalize the passwords (along with other personal information) in order to publish a cleaned database.

Comment: Err, could you clarify the statement "The salt should be a large randomly generated value"?  Would I add that random value salt via the traditional means of string concatenation?

Does: `update account set pswhash = crypt('global salt' || 'new password' || 'user created date', gen_salt('sha256')) where account_id = 5`
 or something like that actually make sense for creating the initial hash?

Or am I missing something about the crypt() function?

Comment: Yes,  use string concatenation of the random value, also use the digest function. 
`pswhash = digest('global salt'||"password"||primary_key, "sha256")`  Using the id makes sure the resulting hash is unqie even if 2 people both use the same password and create an account on the same day.  You could make some improvements to the salt generation,  but this is a lot better than most implementations i have seen.

Comment: Yeah, I tried getting access to pgcrypto, but installing the (postgresql-contrib) package that it's supposed to be in doesn't seem to allow access, how do you get access to digest()?

Comment: Ah, looks like I have to actually run some sql from the module before the functions are available, not just run the install.

Comment: The documentation on the pgcrypto page is pretty good, and clarifies why this is a really silly way to do a hash.  In fact, a recipe for disaster.  Use the crypt function, with the 'bf' hash instead.  See more, including how to do a custom crack with a few billion salted hashes a second at http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: This last comment by @nealmcb is correct but he doesn't say why, he leaves it for you to dig up the answer in the PGSQL docs. The reason is that if you compute the hash on the DB then the password gets sent over the network to the DB, where it may be intercepted. This problem can be mitigated by encrypting the DB connection, but I'd say it's best to avoid sending a cleartext password over the network any more times than absolutely necessary, since each is a potential opportunity for a hacker to intercept it.

Answer (score 10):

Examples and documentation on: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html

```
UPDATE ... SET pswhash = crypt('new password', gen_salt('md5'));

SELECT pswhash = crypt('entered password', pswhash) FROM ... ;
```

Comment: Yeah, pgcrypto looks like what I'm looking for, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the usage, is the example usage saying that I don't have to hardcode my own salt into the hash?

I.e. I do no longer have to provide my own salt data like: `update account set pswhash = crypt('global salt' || 'new password' || 'user created date', gen_salt('sha256')) where account_id = 5` ?  or is salting still a manual process?

Comment: Using the md5 algorithm, without any iteration count (adaptation for increases in hashing speed over time) is a recipe for disaster.  Instead, use 'bf':  gen_salt('bf').  See more, including how to do a custom crack with a few billion salted hashes a second at http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: @Tchalvak correct - you no longer have to provide your own salt data.  In fact the gen_salt also encodes the algorithm, which should really be 'bf' as I note above - see the reference for more.  Given the use of 'bf', this answer is far superior to the one by rook.

Comment: This is the right answer. You should not use the `digest` function to encrypt passwords, it's not secure enough. Just make sure you use the Blowfish algoritm and not MD5.