# How to store passwords exclusively through PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, security, logging, passwords, plaintext

How would I store passwords *exclusively* in PostgreSQL? I am aware of the [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) library that can be used with PostgreSQL as is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647158/how-can-i-hash-passwords-in-postgresql), or below:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES ('jdoe', crypt('password', gen_salt('md5')));
```

However, it is still possible that passwords would be stored in plain text within PostgreSQL server logs. Another complicating factor is I do not have direct control over the log configuration.

Is there any way to completely hide the values in a server column, even from the logs?

Comment: At this point: do the encryption client-side.

Comment: Use built-in Postgres users?