# Error using PostgreSQL digest function trying to check password

Tags: postgresql, sha256, digest

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 and trying to comprehend how to store passwords with digest and crypt functions within the pgcrypto module.
I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "usuarios" (
"id" integer NOT NULL ,
"password" varchar(120),
CONSTRAINT usuarios_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I succesfully saved the first row with this query:

```
INSERT INTO public.usuarios VALUES (DEFAULT,digest('somesalt' || 'mypass','sha256'));
```

I took the idea of the global salt and the digest using the sha256 algorithm reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647158/how-can-i-hash-passwords-in-postgresql) and the official [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgcrypto.html) following the example using crypt()

My problem is, when I try to compare the password in pgAdmin with the following query:

```
SELECT (usuarios.password = digest('somesalt' || 'mypass','sha256')) AS Match FROM usuarios;
```

I get an error mismatching password type( varchar) and digest type (bytea). I have been looking around for a workaround or how the cast would be but cannot find it or, maybe cannot understand what's under my nose.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your digest, eg (note the `::varchar` after digest):

```
SELECT (usuarios.password = digest('somesalt' || 'mypass','sha256')::varchar) AS Match FROM usuarios;
```

Also note that **sha256 isn't really good for password hashing**, and the [PostgreSQL has better functions for password hashing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html#AEN170928). Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18687445/478237).

Comment: Edited. So it's better to use crypt than digest? Because obviously md5 is not an option so, if I use crypt, what could be a good algorithm to use? Or is it different postgres md5 than the original md5, is it ok to use it?

Comment: Yes, if possible with bf algorithm. This table in documentation shows how resistant to bruteforcing the crypt algorithms are: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html#PGCRYPTO-HASH-SPEED-TABLE

Comment: Oh!, thanks, I was a little confused on which function to use